# How to tell python not to interpret hash symbol as comment?

Tags: python, sed, comments, cron, os.system

I wanted to turn on and turn off crone job from os.system command written in python. Basically, using sed command to comment/uncomment the crontab line to control the job schedule.

But when I put this command as shown below, python interpret as text after # as comment.

```
import os
os.system("crontab -l | sed '/^\*.*heightSQL.py/s/^/#/' | crontab -")
```

Is there any way to tell python not to interpret # as comment symbol?

Comment: Why do you need the hash symbol?

Comment: In a string literal, Python itself will already ignore the hash. It's just another character.

Comment: It could be your editor isn't displaying it correctly, but python will understand it.

Comment: I think that it is your command that is invalid: try `os.system("echo sed '/^\*.*heightSQL.py/s/^/#/'")`, you will see that the `#` is ok.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately, it doesn't consider hash as another character while running it into command as shown. For example, print ("#John") gives the output #John as you said, but not in this particular case

Comment: @fredtantini However, your method is useful but got another issue here. "echo crontab -l | sed '/heightSQL.py/s/^#//' | crontab -" produces an error:  "-":1: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no issue with the hash symbol but your quoting is not proper.  Try this:

```
os.system(r"crontab -l | sed '/^\*.*heightSQL.py/s/^/#/' | crontab -")
```

And btw:  Are you sure `crontab -l` produces proper output while `crontab -` is already running?  I'm not.  But that's beside the point here.

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify that the change is a `r'raw string'` literal, it took a while to spot it.

Comment: The longer you need to spot it the better you remember it ;-)  (I'm only half joking ...)

Comment: Its working, the only thing is I needed to run it not as sudo.