# Apache access to php for python script doesn't work

Tags: php, python, apache, raspberry-pi

I know that there are many similar questions and solutions available everywhere for this situation. Apology for the repetition, let me describe my pain:
All efforts to give permission to python script for php based web access goes in vain. No any kind of permission works in my situation:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['CronON']))
{
exec("sudo python /var/www/cron_on.py");
}
if (isset($_POST['CronOFF']))
{
exec("sudo python /var/www/cron_off.py");
}
?>

  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <table
 style="width: 75%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
 border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">CRON ON</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">CRON OFF</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="CronON">ON</button></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="CronOFF">OFF</button></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Pressing the button doesn't product any output, no change at all. This question is a follow-up from my previous question: [How to tell python not to interpret hash symbol as comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42652222/3365754)